# How to get only Items that are within specific Category from RSS Feed

Tags: c#, rss

Im writing an RSS-Reader (sort of) that should only output Items that are within of a Category named "FF - Titel-Themen" (Link to the RSS Feed is [here](https://www.ffw-muenchen.de/news-feed/)). I have search now for quite a time and couldn't find anything and because i´m new to this whole RSS with C# thing its not making anything easier. I hope my question make sense...

Comment: How are you currently parsing the RSS feed's XML?

Comment: with SyndicationFeed and currently it outputs all Items from the Feed regardless of the category

Comment: I had a quick look at the docs so maybe I'm misunderstanding, but can't you check the item's categories property?

Comment: I haven't even thought of that, it works now. Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: I recommend answering your own question with the solution so that it can help other people in future. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("feed url / xml file");
SyndicationFeed RSSFeed = SyndicationFeed.Load(xmlReader);
xmlReader.Close();
List<string> AllCategories = new List<string>();
foreach (SyndicationItem SyndicationItem in RSSFeed.Items)
        {
            foreach (SyndicationCategory category1 in SyndicationItem.Categories)
            {
                if (!Categories_All.Contains(category1.Name))
                {
                    Categories_All.Add(category1.Name);
                }
            }
        }
SyndicationCategory SelectedCategory = new SyndicationCategory("Your specific Category");
        foreach (SyndicationItem SyndicationItem in RSSFeed.Items)
        {
            foreach (SyndicationCategory syndicationCategory in SyndicationItem.Categories)
            {
                if (syndicationCategory.Name == SelectedCategory.Name)
                {
                    // DO STUFF WHAT YOU WANT TO DO WITH THE ITEMS
                }
            }
        }
```